# Monero GUI, cant sync wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization

after days of using it, it still hasnt finished syncing yet.
And for now, it even cant connect and status is "Network status Disconnected". (Stop/start deamon simetimes failed, sometimes it start but with status Disconnected)

I've tried edit deamon startup flags with --block-sync-size 20 but did not help.

I am on Mac OS High Sierra

Please, any suggestion?
Thank you

My log:

Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081

Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081

Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081

Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081

Height: 117275/117275 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 15.05 MH/s, v1, update needed, 0(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 0m 18s

Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. please start Monero GUI
2. set view only wallet
3. set Blockchain location
4. restart  Monero GUI
5. ok ^_^
   [image]

Comment: what do you mean blockchain location?

Comment: it looks good, syncing 48hours now and still ok. Thank you Liberxure