# Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon

My GUi got stuck so i removed p2pdata and tried block size command .. Instead of getting unstuck i get the error :Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081

Also tried [Monero GUI, cant sync wallet](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7645/monero-gui-cant-sync-wallet) with no success

EDIT: By stuck i mean stuck synchronizing

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with reinstallation